# BEA-382040: Failed to set the value of context variable "body". Value must be an instance of {http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Body

Tags: oracle, osb

I have created a OSB service in which both business and proxy services were created based on same wsdl file, and in the proxy message flow i have used routing options with "Use inbound operation for outbound", and i have developed complete flow in sbconsole 11g

When i started testing the service, i'm getting the below response.

```
The invocation resulted in an error: .
<soap:Envelope  xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
<soap:Code>
<soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value>
</soap:Code>
<soap:Reason>
<soap:Text  xml:lang="en">
BEA-382040: Failed to set the value of context variable "body". Value must be an instance of {http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Body.
</soap:Text>
</soap:Reason>
<soap:Detail>
<con:fault  xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context">
<con:errorCode>BEA-382040</con:errorCode>
<con:reason>
Failed to set the value of context variable "body". Value must be an instance of {http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Body.
</con:reason>
<con:location>
<con:path>response-pipeline</con:path>
<con:error-handler>true</con:error-handler>
</con:location>
</con:fault>
</soap:Detail>
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So please help in resolving the issue.

Comment: Are you using any **Replace** action in your proxy service where you're replacing the entire node instead of replacing the node contents?

Comment: Nope, im not using any actions except routing, and in that as well, i'm just using the option "use inbound operation for outbound"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your external service doesn't return soap body. Are you sure your invoked service return it?

Comment: There is an issue with my business service, so do you think this is the issue

Comment: You can invoke directly (without osb), your external service and see what it return's.